# NSURL memory problems in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, nsurl

In my app, I have two viewcontrollers that have NSURL requests: to a local PDF file and an external web page:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

var pdf =  NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(currentProduct?.productInfo, ofType:"pdf")!)
var request = NSURLRequest(URL:pdf!)
```

After leaving these pages, not all the memory allocated to them is freed up. So after some time, memory overloads and the app crashes.

Any suggestions on how to fix this memory leak is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `url` or `pdf`. It is the view controller itself that is leaking. You need to talk about how you summon it and (in particular) what you do that you think would release it.

Comment: Through a bottom toolbar, I am using a Show Segue to go to the PDF or Web page:   

     if segue.identifier == "showInfo" {
    var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as InfoViewController
                secondScene.currentProduct = currentProduct
                }

On the exit, I’m relying on the top nav bar “Back.”

Comment: I am thinking that it isn't "destroying" the respective instances of the web/pdf viewcontroller. I'm not sure how you go about doing that in Swift.

Comment: Implement `deinit` to log to the console in both view controllers. If you go from A to B and then back to A and you don't see logging from B, B is leaking.

Comment: Similarly, implement logging in `viewDidLoad` for both view controllers. It tells you that a new copy is coming into existence. If you are getting multiple copies of A or B simultaneously, there's your problem.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the tips. Finally, getting back to this (after having take a break for a few weeks). Using deinit to trace whether the view controllers are closing, I am clicking back and forth between A and B. I am finding that they aren't deinitializing. That is, until all of sudden all instances of them close (and the deinit message that I placed shows up with the six times that I did switch between the view controllers). Perhaps that is ARC in action? I'm not sure, but how do you tell the specific view controller to "kill" itself when you move to the next.

Comment: One possible implication is that something is keeping you alive. Timers, notification observers, various things can cause retain cycles. Another explanation, though, is that perhaps you set this up wrong in the storyboard, so that B doesn't go "back" to A at all, but instead creates a whole _new_ A on top of itself; that's a common mistake.

Comment: After debugging more, my previous observation is incorrect. In my app, I swipe from the start page A to the next page/view controller B and then to the third vc C. From A B C, you can access a PDF and Web page. The instances of the PDF and Web page do close when I hit Back navigation. The parent vc B and C close only when you hit Back. A is always kept alive. So by the time I reach C and open up the Web page, you have A, B, C open plus the Web page. Is that normal? I want to add 5 more pages (D,E,F,G,H). But I'll run out of memory if all the preceding pages are kept alive until you hit Back.